# Symfony : how to get all user posts related with oneToMany relation

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, twig, one-to-many

I have two entity User and Booking which are related with oneToMany relationship, when a user ake a booking the user id is saved in the user_id column table of booking, I want in my controller to retrieve all the user's booking !

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="bookings")
 * @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $user;

    public function setUser(?User $user): self
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }
```

---

```
/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Booking::class, mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $bookings;

/**
     * @return Collection|Booking[]
     */
    public function getBookings(): Collection
    {
        return $this->bookings;
    }

    public function addBooking(Booking $booking): self
    {
        if (!$this->bookings->contains($booking)) {
            $this->bookings[] = $booking;
            $booking->setUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

---

```
/**
     * @Route("/user/profile/my-bookings", name="user.profile.bookings")
     */

    public function getUserBookings(){
        $user = $this->getUser()->getBookings();

        return $this->render('user/user.bookings.html.twig', [
            'user'=>$user
        ]);
    }
```

when trying to get the connected user and call getBookings() method it doesn't return any thing !

here what does $this->getUser return :

[image]

Comment: what does $this->getUser() return?

Comment: Question updated see the image attached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I just forgot to add fetch EAGER to the OneToMany relationship  between User and Booking !

Answer (score 1):

You can print it from twig by using

```
{% for booking in user.bookings %}
    {{booking}}
{% endfor %}
```

Or retrieve it into your controller with PHP:

```
foreach($user->getBookings() as $booking){
    echo $booking->getYourField();
}
```

Comment: That's not working , it does not know the getBookings method and phpstorm show this message : " Potentially polymorphic call. User does not have members in its hierarchy "

Comment: Well... Thats normal as you assigned `$this->getUser()->getBookings()` to the variable `user` and not the real user

Comment: @DarkBee can you explain more ? the real user is the loggedIn user isn't it !

Comment: You are rendering your 'user' variable with getBookings() data, what if you render 'user' with $this->getUser() and then access bookings inside Twig using user.bookings?

Comment: I tried it,  field or method not found for bookings !!

Comment: Do this in your template, `{{ dump(user) }}`

Comment: @DarkBee yes I did the array collection is empty !

Comment: Well that proves that your variable `user` is not a `App\Entity\User` right?

Comment: @DarkBee I see, I just want to add a Booking object to the loggedIn user when he book a car !